# AWS : monitoring if service is running

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We are using zabbix to monitor our instance, during the the instance creation chef-recipes install and register zabbix. We have modified the zabbix recipe to by-pass registration if it fails, so that the rest of the services are deployed and are functional. Is it possible to set up alarms in AWS to check if zabbix registration is successful ? In other word, how to setup custom monitors for a  instance ?

Answer (score 1):

You can publish your own [custom metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/publishingMetrics.html) and configure [cloudwatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) to monitor them as well as trigger [alarms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudwatch_concepts.html#CloudWatchAlarms) if needed.